# Python/Selenium syntax error

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I wrote this code, what it does is importing webdriver, opens webpage for my mail account , makes a new tab, swaps back to the last tab, writes in credentials and clicks "submit"

The problem is everything underneath wont do anything.. at the end you can see im trying to swap tabs again, but it does not work. I will print the error message below.

CODE:

```
#Magnus
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import webbrowser
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

#Åpne Mail
browser.get("https://mail.gasta.no")
browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
time.sleep(1)
browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)
time.sleep(1)
username = browser.find_element_by_name("login_username")
password = browser.find_element_by_name("secretkey")
username.send_keys("") 
password.send_keys("")
login_attempt = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type='submit']")
login_attempt.submit()

browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Python33/Scripts/chrome test v1.py", line 21, in <module>

browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)

File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.48.0-
py3.3.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 354, in 
find_element_by_tag_name

return self.find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value=name)

File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.48.0-
py3.3.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 712, in find_element

{'using': by, 'value': value})['value']

File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.48.0-
py3.3.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute

self.error_handler.check_response(response)

File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.48.0-
py3.3.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 181, in 
check_response

raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate 
element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"body"}

Stacktrace:

at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ 
(file:///c:/users/magnus/appdata/local/temp/tmpceirmg/extensions/fxdriver@google
code.com/components/driver-component.js:10659)

at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement 
(file:///c:/users/magnus/appdata/local/temp/tmpceirmg/extensions/fxdriver@google
code.com/components/driver-component.js:10668)

at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h 
(file:///c:/users/magnus/appdata/local/temp/tmpceirmg/extensions/fxdriver@google
code.com/components/command-processor.js:12534)

at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ 
(file:///c:/users/magnus/appdata/local/temp/tmpceirmg/extensions/fxdriver@google
code.com/components/command-processor.js:12539)

at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< 
(file:///c:/users/magnus/appdata/local/temp/tmpceirmg/extensions/fxdriver@google
code.com/components/command-processor.js:12481)

>>>
```

Comment: when I run your code everything works as expected. firefox is launched, a new tab is opened, execution returns to original tab in firefox and form is submitted, execution turns to second tab where no webpage has been loaded, I used browser.get("http://google.com") to load a new webpage in the 2nd tab and page loads fine. do you maybe have more code after line 21 that you've not displayed in your question?

Comment: for example the same, but another webpage or the same.

browser.get("https://mail.gasta.no")
browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
time.sleep(1)
browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)
time.sleep(1)
username = browser.find_element_by_name("login_username")
password = browser.find_element_by_name("secretkey")
username.send_keys("") 
password.send_keys("")
login_attempt = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type='submit']")
login_attempt.submit()

Comment: I want it to open web, go to my mail, log in , submit, make a new tab, do the excact same to another mail of mine, the problem is that it only work one time, then it goes into error

Comment: I will make a new question with the excact code im trying to make work :)

Comment: What i want:

Open browser and search a website , write in username and password and submit, then i was to make a new tab and open another webpage , write in credentials and submit.

The problem i have is making a new tab and do the excact same thing.

Comment: I dont know how , but if i open the login.live.com first it works.. thanks!